# The free object of the variety constructed by an m-generated subalgebra

Tags: universal-algebra, universal-property

A modal algebra is an algebra $\langle M,\vee,\wedge, ',0,1,^\circ\rangle$ such that $\langle M,\vee,\wedge, ',0,1,\rangle$ is a Boolean algebra and the operation $^\circ$ satisfies $(x\wedge y)^\circ= x^\circ\wedge y^\circ$ and $1^\circ=1$.

In the paper "Pretabular Varieties of Modal Algebras" of W. J. Blok on page 110, I faced with the following claim:

Let $A$ be a $0$-generated subalgebra of a modal algebra (or Boolean algebra). Then it is the free object on $0$-generators in the variety $V(A)$.

I did the following steps to prove this claim. Let $C\in V(A)$, there is only empty map from $\emptyset$ to $C$ and $\emptyset$ to $A$. Thus, to satisfy the universal mapping property, we need only find a homomorphism $\varphi: A\to C$. Now, from the fact $C\in HSP(A)$, we have $E_1\in P(A)$ and $E_2\in S(E_1)$ for which $C\in H(E_2)$. If we could find a homomorphism from $E_1$ to $E_2$, the $\varphi$ could be easily obtained, but I think this homomorphism does not generally exist.   However, it exists if we can show that $E_1$ is the only non-empty subalgebra of itself.

After proving this claim, I need to know if a similar claim is true for an $m$-generated subalgebra of an arbitrary algebra.

For a Boolean algebra $A$ generated by $m$ ($m>1$) elements the claim seems to be trivial (as it is mentioned in first answer) since $V(A)$ is equal to the class of all Boolean algebras, refer to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236772/the-variety-generated-by-a-subalgebra-of-a-boolean-algebra?noredirect=1#comment8804559_4236772).

Comment: The subalgebra generated by the empty set is the subalgebra generated by the constants, in this case it's always $\{0,1\}$ for a (nondegenerate) Boolean algebra.

Comment: @Berci your comment is not true since $A$ may has more elements than $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Yes, but the empty set will generate exactly $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

As to the last question, the answer is yes for finite m. We have:

Let A be an m-generated subalgebra of a Boolean algebra (i.e. of 2^(2^m) members). Then it is the free object on m-generators in the variety V(A).

Comment: And by the way, $V(A)=V(\{0,1\})=\{$all Boolean algebras$\}$.